# Stock sparse matrix

Tags: java, file, matrix, storage, sparse-matrix

I have a very huge matrix (like 10000x10000) to store in a file. So obviously it takes quite a lot of useless memory since it has a lot of zeros.

I found in wikipedia a way to store such matrix:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)

I was able to get the three arrays linked to the matrix. But now I wish to make the opposite: Given these three arrays, I would like to restore the original matrix. I know at what column I should place the elements in array A (well it's given in array JA), but I don't know at what row I should place them.

Any help please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work out which row to put them in, you need to use IA and A.

Work backwards and calculate the list

`IA' = {IA[m+1] - IA[m], IA[m] - IA[m-1], IA[m-1] - IA[m-2],..., IA[2]-IA[1], IA[1]-IA[0]}`

the list IA' will tell you how many entries of A to add to the bottom row of the matrix.

You already know where to add them, using J.

So

```
IA' = [4-3, 3-2, 2-0, 0]
IA' = [1,1,2,0]
```

for the wikipedia example listed below:

```
   A  = [5,8,3,6]
   IA = [0,0,2,3,4]
   JA = [0,1,2,1]
```

that means the last element of A goes on the bottom row, the second to last goes on the row up from that, and the first 2 elements of A go on the 3rd row up. The top row has no entries.

reversing IA' to IA'' might make the implementation more straightforward as you can work down the rows instead, and interpret it like this:

```
IA'' = [0,2,1,1]
A    = [5,8,3,6]
```

on the top row, 0 entries. next row has 2 entries [5,3]. next 2 have 1 entry each, [3] and [6] respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @WassimAyari You're welcome, could you accept answer please